# How to use images as error bars

Tags: plotting, graphics, warning-messages

So I'm trying to make a plot using error bars, but instead of errorbars, I'd like to use an image. Let's say we've got the  following plot:
[image]
Instead of these error bars, I want to use the image of a tie fighter (turned on its side) instead. So I've imported the image and turned it on its side. Now the problem I'm facing is how to scale and position it within the plot to function as error bars. Do any of you have any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

EDIT:
So I still can't figure it out, the problem probably lies in that I'm just using uncertainties in y. My code is as follows:

```
Import["http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/swmerchandise/images/4/45/\
Imperial_TIE_Fighter_(27644)_P.gif"];

Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
tijd = {-3, -2, 0, 1, 2}; (*x axis*)
positie = {27.9, 10.2, 1.8, 9.5, 23.3}; (*y axis*)
onzekerheid = {0.5, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.9}; (*Uncertainty*)

errorplot = {{tijd[[#]], positie[[#]]}, 
ErrorBar[onzekerheid[[#]]]} & /@ Range[1, Length[tijd]];
position = Transpose[{tijd, positie}];

errorbar[pos_, err_] :=
  With[
   {s = 0.05},
   With[
    {
     corners =
      {{pos[[#]] - s, pos[[#]] - err[[#]]},
         {pos[[#]] + s, pos[[#]] - err[[#]]},
         {pos[[#]] + s, pos[[#]] + err[[#]]},
         {pos[[#]] - s, pos[[#]] + err[[#]]}} & /@ 
       Range[1, Length[pos]]
 },
{
 Texture[ImageRotate[fighter, \[Pi]/2]],
 Polygon[
  corners,
  VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}
  ]
 }
]
];
```

Comment: Have you tried `ErrorBarFunction`?

Comment: @lowriniak `ErrorBarFunction` is the correct way to approach this, but the examples are rather scarce.

Comment: inleveropgave week 6?

Answer (score 7):

Import your image, you didn't provide one, so I chose this one:

```
im = Import["https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/star-wars-5/24/Tie-\
Fighter-128.png"];
```

This method works only with 2d errorbars:

```
ErrorListPlot[{{{1, 1}, ErrorBar[0.2, 0.3]}, {{2, 2}, 
   ErrorBar[0.2, 0.3]}, {{3, 4}, ErrorBar[0.2, 0.5]}, {{4, 8}, 
   ErrorBar[1, 2]}},
 ErrorBarFunction -> 
  Function[{coords, errs}, {Opacity[0.5], Texture[im], 
    Polygon[{coords + {errs[[1, 1]], errs[[2, 1]]}, 
      coords + {errs[[1, 2]], errs[[2, 1]]}, 
      coords + {errs[[1, 2]], errs[[2, 2]]}, 
      coords + {errs[[1, 1]], errs[[2, 2]]}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't yet been able to figure it out, can you take a look at the code I posted in the top comment?

Comment: @MitchellFaas You can use a constant error for your y-axis, or scale it with the x-error.

Answer (score 6):

I used a slightly different `ErrorBarFunction` to Feyre so I thought I would share my solution too. This should also account for x errors:

```
errorbar[coords_, errs : ErrorBar[{xn_, xp_}, {yn_, yp_}]] := With[
  {s = 0.3},
  With[
   {
      pts = {
        coords + {xn - s, yn},
        coords + {xn + s, yn},
       coords + {xp + s, yp},
       coords + {xp - s, yp}
      }
    },
    {
      Texture[ImageRotate[img, \[Pi]/2]],
      Polygon[
        pts,
        VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}
      ]
    }
  ]
];

ErrorListPlot[
  Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 10}], 
  ErrorBarFunction -> errorbar, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[Tiny]
]
```

[image: tiefighters]

Variables:

s : x scaling for better image size

xn, yn : negative error in x and y

xp, yp : positive error in x and y

img : your chosen TIE fighter image (I couldn't find a decent one labeled for re-use)

Comment: I like your style! Still trying to figure out exactly how to incorperate it though :P I'll leave a comment once I finished that.